# How do you read and write from/into different ElasticSearch clusters using spark and elasticsearch-hadoop?

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, hdfs, elasticsearch-hadoop, distributed-filesystem

**Original title: Besides HDFS, what other DFS does spark support (and are recommeded)?**

I am happily using spark and elasticsearch (with elasticsearch-hadoop driver) with several gigantic clusters.

From time to time, I would like to pull the entire cluster of data out, process each doc, and put all of them into a different Elasticsearch (ES) cluster (yes, data migration too).

Currently, there is no way to read ES data from a cluster into RDDs and write the RDDs into a different one with spark + elasticsearch-hadoop, because that would involve swapping `SparkContext` from RDD. So I would like to write the RDD into object files and then later on read them back into RDDs with different `SparkContext`s.

However, here comes the problem: I then need a DFS(Distributed File System) to share the big files across my entire spark cluster. The most popular solution is HDFS, but I would very much avoid introducing Hadoop into my stack. Is there any other recommended DFS that spark supports?

**Update Below**

Thanks to @Daniel Darabos's answer below, I can now read and write data from/into different ElasticSearch clusters using the following Scala code:

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Spark Migrating ES Data")
conf.set("es.nodes", "from.escluster.com")

val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

val allDataRDD = sc.esRDD("some/lovelydata")

val cfg = Map("es.nodes" -> "to.escluster.com")
allDataRDD.saveToEsWithMeta("clone/lovelydata", cfg)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spark uses the hadoop-common library for file access, so whatever file systems Hadoop supports will work with Spark. I've used it with HDFS, S3 and GCS.

I'm not sure I understand why you don't just use `elasticsearch-hadoop`. You have two ES clusters, so you need to access them with different configurations. `sc.newAPIHadoopFile` and `rdd.saveAsHadoopFile` take `hadoop.conf.Configuration` arguments. So you can without any problems use two ES clusters with the same `SparkContext`.

Comment: thanks for the response. I am using the new read (sc.esRDD) and write (rss.saveToEs) functions proposed by elasticsearch-hadoop. There is no way to read and write from different clusters this way.

Thanks for bringing rdd.saveAsHadoopFile up, I am looking into it to see of I can somehow go from there.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know about these methods (`esRDD` and `saveToEs`). I see they take a `cfg: Map[String, String]` argument. Could that not be used to provide different configurations for reading and writing?

Comment: thanks for the update. I was such an idiot to ignore the cfg. It's working!! I will update my node up to the question for everybody. Thanks again.